# Add Path to File Name in Batch Delete File

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I am trying to write a batch script to delete files listed in in a text file. I have it working fine (have never written a batch script). The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to write it using relative paths so that it can be run on a different computer from the root directory.

The batch script I have is:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (List_of_Files.txt) do del "%%f"
```

The list of files is structured like this:

payroll_page\cf2_2.gif
payroll_page\chart_e.gif
payroll_page\dollar-06.gif
payroll_page\calendar_files\image001.png

What I want to do is to be able to run this batch file from a root directory of the folder structure and delete the files in the subdirectories that are listed. Any help at all with this would be great as I've been banging my head against it for hours.

- Ludovik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest case: as your text file lines have relative paths then the batch file has to be executed from the relative folder in question.

If your text file has fully qualified paths names then it can be launched from anywhere.

Comment: I have tried that without any success. I have a text file with \Test1\Test2\Test.txt   and launch it from the directory above Test1 but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't know what you have tried.  `del "\test1\test2\test.txt"` is only going to delete that exact \path\file from the current drive, if it exists, and can be launched from anywhere on the drive.  Do you get an `Access Denied` error?

Comment: Not that I see, no. For example, let's take:  
Bat File Directory C:\Test                
Text File Content \Test1\Test.txt    File to Delete C:\Test\Test1\Test.txt

Comment: This is a stupid question but I the .bat file just runs without displaying any output. Is there a line I have to add to get the output? Also, have you tried this yourself? It should only take a second.

Comment: place a `pause` command at the bottom, or open a CMD window and launch the batch file.

Comment: It has a strange character before the file, it has an odd symbol in front of the textfile listing. "(StringSymbol)Test\Test1.txt"

Comment: edit your text file, or batch file.  One of them has the odd character in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to delete something from a certain drive, but not in like the system files, you'd have to make a completely valid path. Unless the file is already in the folder the file(s) are contained in, you would be able to do the same, but otherwise, you MIGHT have to run the file in administrator mode.